# will curl share options for multiple transfer

Tags: curl, post

When use a single curl command to do multiple transfer, with the options be shared, for example:
$ curl -v -O http://example.com/page1.html  -s http://example.com/page2.html
Will the -v -O and -s applied to both transfers?
Is there any difference for GET and POST?